# select all anchor tags having onclick using xpath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I want to select all anchor tags on a web page having 'onClick' function defined as an attribute using XPATH. 
The web page i am targeting has anchor tags like this

```
<a href="status.php?op=del&amp;status_id=2" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')">Delete</a>
```

After a lot of searching I found following potential solutions but none of them seem to work. I have tried (and failed)

```
//a[@onclick|@href]
//a[onclick]
//a[@onclick]
//a/@*[name()='onclick']
./*[onclick]  #this should have selected all nodes with onclick function
```

I also tried

```
//a/@onclick
```

but this only returns the onclick function definition where as i want the entire anchor tag.

Question: How do i get all the anchor tags that have onclick function defined as an attribute using XPATH?

Comment: `//a[@onclick]` looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath `//a[@onclick]` should work.

Try executing this in the console of your browser to alert each anchor:

```
(function(){
  var withOnclick = document.evaluate('//a[@onclick]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
  var anchor = withOnclick.iterateNext();
  while (anchor) {
    alert(anchor.outerHTML);
    anchor = withOnclick.iterateNext();
  }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("a[onclick]")` should work to find all anchors with onclick if you're using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to do it using

```
//a[@onclick]
```

Earlier i was applying this on incorrect response object and hence was not able to get the links.
To add further, to get the 'url' values one could do:

```
HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//a[@onclick]/@href').extract()
```

this will return the list of all the links that belong to an anchor tag having 'onclick' function defined as an attribute.

Thanks for your answers.